# How to control data's edit state in gridcolumn?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, gridcontrol

in my `gridcontrol`, I want to set `3 backgroud colors` for `different state` of the data in the cell. For example, the cell's `default backgroud color is green,` when user edited the cell, change the `backgroud color to red`, after saving completed, change the background `color to yellow`.

My current solutions is every properties also have `coresponding state property`. For example, a property named Country, there's another property named CountryState. CountryState's type is a `enum type`, which contains 3 values: default, edited and saved. Then binding the gridcontrol's cell background color to the state property.

But `I don't think this is a good solution`, is there any other solution to deal with this scenario?

Comment: Did you implemented `inotifypropertychanged` interface on your class??

Comment: @Moumit yes, but it cannot check the status

Comment: Keep only one property `State` .. and on edit of `any property` update it

Answer (score 0):

Use only one `property` name `state` to `notify` changes ..

**Example:**

```
public class BookViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _Title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _Title; }
        set
        {
            CheckAndNotifyState(_Title, value, "Title");
            _Title = value;
        }
    }

    string _AuthorName;
    public string AuthorName
    {
        get { return _AuthorName; }
        set
        {
            CheckAndNotifyState(_AuthorName, value, "AuthorName");
            _AuthorName = value;
        }
    }

    State _State;
    public State State
    {
        get { return _State; }
        set
        {
            CheckAndNotifyState(_State, value, "State");
            _State = value;
        }
    }


    private void CheckAndNotifyState(object oldValue, object newValue, string propertyName)
    {
        if (oldValue != newValue)
        {
            State = State.Edit;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}

public enum State
{
    Default,
    Edit,
    Saved
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want to know which property is changed, in this way, I can know the model is changed, but I don't know which property is changed.

Comment: Why??If you followed `MVVM` pattern than `On modification on any data` will trigger `INotifyPropertyChanged`.. As an example .. If you modify `Book title` as mention in above example then `the setter` property automatically get called ... remember to keep `BookViewModel` using `ObservableCollection<BookViewModel>`

Comment: Here are two `good` example on this http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/responding-to-changes/ & http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e06010/observablecollection-in-wpf/

Comment: thanks for your remind. But my scenario is I need to save a specific edited property to service to save the data, not the entire object.

Comment: @Allen4Tech can you explore your `code` .. or same `demo code` .. i didnot getting you..